# Create multiple lists at once

Tags: python, list, loops

I have 10 customers and one depot 0. For each customer I now want to create a shuttle route from depot, to customer and back to depot in the following format:

```
Shuttle_route_i = [0, i, 0]
```

But I don't want to create a dictionary, because later the routes will be changed, compiled, etc.

Is there any way to get this?

My previous code was:

```
def Generierung_Pendelrouten (Koordinaten):
    d = {}
    for i in range(1, len(Koordinaten)):
        d['Pendelroute_{0}'.format(i)] = [0,i,0]
    return d
```

With the result:

```
Pendelrouten:
{'Pendelroute_1': [0, 1, 0], 'Pendelroute_2': [0, 2, 0], 'Pendelroute_3': [0, 3, 0], 'Pendelroute_4': [0, 4, 0], 'Pendelroute_5': [0, 5, 0], 'Pendelroute_6': [0, 6, 0], 'Pendelroute_7': [0, 7, 0], 'Pendelroute_8': [0, 8, 0], 'Pendelroute_9': [0, 9, 0], 'Pendelroute_10': [0, 10, 0]}
```

But with the dictionary I can't then continue to work as desired.

My other idea was to work with a for loop:

```
for i in range (1,11):
    route = [] 
    route.append(0)
    route.append(i)
    route.append(0)
print(route)
```

But then you get only the last route [0, 10, 0] output. This is the format in which I want to have all 10 routes.

Comment: What have you tried for yourself so far and where did you get stuck? Can you show us the code and perhaps the error?

Comment: Please edit this post and include your code.

Comment: I have added my code.

Comment: Move `route = []` **before** the `for` loop, so it won't be cleared on every iteration.

Comment: you can return tuple and assign it `def a(): return ([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])` then `(b, c) = a()` - will assign that two lists to `b`, and `c`... if that is not the case - please provide code that depicts a problem.

Comment: A list of lists would probably be sufficient. Is there really any reason to use strings as `dict` keys when the string portion doesn't contribute any information? `[[0,i,0] for i, _ in enumerate(Koordinaten, start=1)]`.